# Neo4J find the number(SIZE) of relationships between nodes

Tags: neo4j, numbers, cypher, relationship

I am trying to return a set of nodes where there is more than n outgoing relationships of the same kind. The specific use case is given a set of movies which actors have contributed to more than one of those movies.

I have tried multiple methods of `COUNTing` and `SIZE`, but cannot figure out whether this is even possible in Neo4J

```
MATCH (cw:CreativeWork) WHERE cw.officialTitle IN ['Antz', 'The Specialist ']
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE SIZE((p)-[:contributedTo]-(cw)) > 1
RETURN p, cw
```

This will return the two Creative Works specified and all the people who have contributed to the title, based on the relationship `:contributedTo`. Two actors in the list have contributed to both titles, and I am interested in returning just those two.

[image]

This query for example returns no results:

```
MATCH (cw:CreativeWork) WHERE cw.officialTitle IN ['Antz', 'The Specialist ']
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE SIZE((p)-[:contributedTo]-(cw)) > 1
RETURN p, cw
```

Comment: Your both queries are same, can you check once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of your query value of `SIZE()` will be always **0** or **1** (Except if there are two or more relationships between any pair of `Person` and `CreativeWork`). The reason for this is your query is aggregating the `SIZE` (or `Count`) over `Person` and `CreativeWork`.(Same as Group by on both of these)

You can use the following query which `COUNTS` `CreativeWorks` for each `Person` (This query returns a list of CreativeWork for Person.
):

```
MATCH (cw:CreativeWork) WHERE cw.officialTitle IN ['Antz', 'The Specialist']
MATCH (p:Person)-[:contributedTo]-(cw)
WITH p,count(cw) as rels, collect(cw) as cws
WHERE rels > 1
RETURN p,cws
```

**You can modify the above query to look simple as follows(Both performs the same):**

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:contributedTo]-(cw:CreativeWork)
WHERE cw.officialTitle IN ['Antz', 'The Specialist']
WITH p,count(cw) as rels, collect(cw) as cws
WHERE rels > 1
RETURN p,cws
```

> NOTE: There is a space at the end of the last title in the list (in
>   your query).

Answer (score 0):

@Raj's last query can be simplified:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:contributedTo]-(cw:CreativeWork)
WHERE cw.officialTitle IN ['Antz', 'The Specialist']
WITH p, collect(cw) as cws
WHERE SIZE(cws) > 1
RETURN p, cws
```